# Ubuntu graphics issue on VMware

Tags: 13.04, vmware

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on VMware Workstation. All is good, except that there's this graphics issue with the Launcher and the top bar; the buttons do work, however.

[image]

I downloaded CCSM for a try, but couldn't go further with any of the options. Could anyone help please?

This is an Inspiron 1525 with Intel graphics.

Thanks

Comment: Did you perform all system updates and reboot the guest? Did you also install the VMware guest tools? What VMware workstation version are you on and what kind of host OS? Please *edit* your question to incorporate more details.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by turning off 3D Accerelation in VM settings, but it's incredibly slow now.